# Two people walking towards each other and a passing Train

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Two people are walking towards each other alongside a railway track. A freight train overtakes one of them in $20$ seconds and exactly $10$ minutes later meets the other person coming from the opposite direction. The train passes this person in $18$ seconds. Assume that speeds are constant throughout. How long after the train has passed the second person will the two people meet?

Now this is a rather surprising question because:

1. when I was taught this in class, teacher arrived at $89.7$ minutes,
2. I arrived at $92$ minutes $22$ seconds,
3. mostly answers on internet show $90$ minutes as answer,
4. a google book mentions $92$ minutes $42$ seconds as the answer and
5. another google book mentions the answer as "cannot be determined".

Let the speed of train, 1st person and 2nd person be $z$, $x$ and $y$ m/s.

Then everyone arrives at $z=10x+9y$.

That's where similarity ends. Now, while finding the required time taken ($T$) for the two people to meet is where all the problem befells:

1. $T= \frac{10(10x+9y)-10x-0.3(x+y)}{x+y}$
2. $T= \frac{600(10x+10y)+20(9x+9y)-638(x+y)}{x+y}$
3. $T= \frac{600(z+y)-600(x+y)}{x+y}$
4. (Assumes the speed of 2 people to be same)
5. Only answer is mentioned as: Cannot be determined

Please help. (Hoping consensus between MSE members)

Comment: @GregMartin, the "men" was present in question itself and on google also, "men" has been used. Since I have referenced google search results too, is it then alright to change it to "persons" here?

Comment: I feel compelled to upvote your answer, because of the comment that you left following my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you for your answer and the upvote :-)

Comment: @InanimateBeing I find "people" and "persons" equally good ("people" is just more common).

Comment: @GregMartin I meant why change from men to people? If you search google, everywhere men is used.

Comment: "Men" is gender-exclusive (the gender of the characters is irrelevant to the problem, and assuming all people are automatically male perpetuates the unwelcoming environment for women that exists in mathematics). "People" is gender-inclusive. That "men" is used everywhere is just a symptom of how widespread sexism is.

Comment: @GregMartin Alright, thank you for informing me and editing too.

Comment: Just going to comment by relativity we may assume any one of the agents (either person, or train) is stationary.  (Although if you make the train stationary you will have one person walking backwards). [If train = $t$ and $x$ is the speed of the person walking toward the the train and $y$ the speed of the person walking the same direction of the train, the situation would play out exactly the same with $t' = t+x$ and $0 = x-x$ and $y' = y+ x$.  Or it'd be exactly this same with $t''=t-y$ and $x'' = x+y$ and $0=y-y$.  Or if $0 =t-t$ and $x'''= x+t$ and $y''' =y-t$]

Comment: Hypothetically it is possible that the problem refers to two people one named Adam who is a man who likes grunge rock and is wearing a yellow hat and the other is named William who is a man who likes classical music and has a job as a veterinarian's assistant.  In that case it is "2 men".  But as stated it just sounds kind of old-fashionedly sexist as obviously nothing specific about the people are important so they should be as generic as possible.  ... but then again, you didn't write the problem so I do not think it is on you.

Comment: @fleablood 1. Train stationary is nice perspective but if a person walks backward will they ever meet? Even though relativity is just used to make things easier for computation/understanding. 2. "exactly the same with": here are you referring to some answer post below or something else? 3. $t'$ and $var'$ represent what? (It might be common but I need a little explanation.)

Comment: @fleablood Adam and William really aren't needed, I already got it. Just asked because if anyone searches google they'll find the problem in its original form anyways so I asked if it meant anything here and GregMartin gave a nice answer.

Comment: "Train stationary is nice perspective but if a person walks backward will they ever meet? "  Of course!  Because the person walking toward them would be walking faster than they are walking backwards.. ". "exactly the same with": here are you referring to some answer post below or something else?"  I am referring to the question being asked.  The situation in the question being asked is *exactly* the same as if one of the three agents is stationary.

Comment: @fleablood even if P1 is slower/faster/has same speed as P2, they'll meet anyways, no assumptions needed then why using relativity we are finding ourselves needing to make an assumption that P1 is faster than P2? I think assuming train stationary we have 3 scenarios: When actually train is behind, between and ahead of both the persons. Or so I thought, but it turns out all the 3 are same. Let speed of train be t, P1 be x, P2 be y and the direction in which P1 is moving be positive. Then, for all 3 scenarios, v(P1)= -(t-x) and v(p2)=-(t+y). Now it doesn't matter if x><=y, they'll meet anyways.

Comment: We don't know that $P_1$ is faster than than $P_2$.  We know that $P_1 + T$ is faster than $|P_2 - T|$.  We know that because we know that the train is faster than $P_2$ (it passed $P_2$ when they are both walking in the same direction) and because $P_1$ and $P_2$ *do* have to meet as they are walking in opposite direction.

Comment: I am having quite a dilemma now. I have received 4 beautiful and coherent answers by now and my problem stands solved and so I would like it to look that way, that is, "Problem is solved" but I can't just tickmark one answer, they're all equally valuable and thus upvoted by me. What do I do? Should I just edit my question header and add "[Solved]" in it?

Comment: @InanimateBeing: Pl. have a look at my answer just posted. Such approaches were devised when my granddaughter was preparing for a management entrance test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  Let $t_0$ be the velocity of the train.  Let $x_0$ be the velocity of the person walking in the same direction of the train.  Lets assume these values are positive.  The velocity of the person walking in the other direction is negative because they are walking in the opposite direction. Let $-y_0$ be the velocity of that person.

Now... Newtonian relativity.... Imagine the entire situation, both people, train, and miles of train track you on a platform traveling with a constant velocity of $c$.  If we ignore wind resistance and near light speed compaction nothing will change.  The train will still pass everyone at the same time.  So we can add a constant $c$ to $t_0, y_0,$ and $x_0$ and it will not change our answer and results.

So let $c = y_0$.  Now let $t = t_0 + y_0$, $x = x_0 + y_0$ and $y = -y_0 + y_0 = 0$. This would be a situation where the second person is standing still, the first person is walking toward him with a combined speed of her "real" speed plus the second person's speed, and the train is travelling at its "real" speed plus the second guy's speed.  Nothing changes.  Another way of thinking of this is to imagine the referee guy who is watching and timing this is on a floating surfboard and gliding past the scene at a velocity of $y_0$.

Okay....  Now let $U$ be one unit equal to one train-length.  The train passes person 2 in $18$ sec so we know that $t = \frac {1U}{18sec}$.

Now the train passes the first person in $20$ sec. The distance the first person walks in the $20$ seconds is $x\cdot 20sec$.  So the distance the train traveled in passing person 1 is its own length plus $x\cdot 20sec$ or $1U + x\cdot 20sec$.  But if it took $20 sec$ we can also express that distance as $20\sec \cdot \frac {1U}{18} = \frac {10}9 U$.

So $1U + x\cdot 20sec= \frac {10}9 U$
$x\cdot 20sec = \frac 19 U$
$x =\frac {1U}{180 sec}$.

Now lets fix this point and place in time.  The tail of the train has just past person 1.  Let's call the point where the head of the train is now $0$.  Person 1 is $1U$ away and lets call that $ - 1U$.  And person 2 is standing still at some point ahead.  It takes the head of the train $10$ minutes $= 600$ secs to reach him so he is at $600\sec \cdot \frac {1U}{18sec} = \frac {300}9 U$.

Now let $18$ seconds pass so that the train passes person 2.  So $618$ second have passed since the train passed person 1 at $-1U$.  So person 1 is now at point $-1U + 618\cdot\frac {1U}{180sec}=\frac {73}{30}U$.

So the distance between Person 1 and Person 2 is now $\frac {300}9U -\frac {73}{30}U=\frac {309}{10}U$.

And now the time will take for person 2 to reach person 1 is $\frac {distance}{speed} = \frac {\frac {309}{10}U}{\frac {1U}{180sec}}=5562 sec =92 min 42 sec$

While the method is sound, we could have tried to solve it without the relativity shift but we'd have had an unsolved variable in all our equations that would have cancelled out in the end.

======

You asked in comments if changing our frame of reference changes our measured distances and speeds and give a wrong answer. It *does* change ou measured distance and therefore our speeds but not our times.

If we set person 2's speed (velocity *without* direction to $c$ and the train length to $1U$ we get. Let $t = $ train speed and $x=$ person 1's speed.

It takes $18$ seconds for the train to pass person 2.  In $18$ seconds at a speed of $c\frac {U}{sec}$ person 2 will have walked $18c U$.  The train in the opposite direction passes him after he walks $18c U$ so the train will have traveled $1U - 18cU = (1-18c)U$.  Thus the trains speed is $\frac {(1-18c)U}{18 sec}=(\frac 1{18} - c)\frac U{sec}$.

Let figure out Persons 1 speed.  In $20$ seconds she would have walked $20\sec\cdot x\frac U{sec}=20 xU$ if her speed is $x\frac U{sec}$.  Meanwhile the head of the train would have traveled $20\cdot (\frac 1{18} - c)= (\frac {10}9 -20c)U$. But as person 2 and the tail of the train are both at $20xU$ we have $20xU + 1U =  (\frac {10}9 -20c)U$.  Thus $x\frac U{sec}=(\frac 1{180} - c)\frac {U}{sec}$.

Now lets consider that we've had $20$ seconds (for the train to pass Person 1) and $10min = 600sec$ for the trains head to meet person 2.  And $18$ seconds to pass Person two.  The $638 sec$. Let's figure out where Person 1 is and where Person 2 and the tail of the train is.

Person  1 will have traveled $638(\frac 1{180}-c)U=(\frac{319}{90}- 638c)U$.  The head of the train will have traveled $638(\frac 1{18} - c)U=(\frac {319}9 - 638c)U$ and so its tail and Person 2 will be at $(\frac {319}9 - 638c)U-1U = (\frac {310}9 - 638c)U$.

And the distance between Person 1 and person 2 would be $(\frac {310}9 - 638c)U - (\frac {319}{90} - 638c)U = \frac {3100-319}{90}U =\frac {2781}{90}U$.

The combined speed of Person 1 and 2 is $(\frac 1{180} - c)\frac U{sec} + c\frac {U}{sec} = \frac 1{180}\frac {U}{sec}$.

So  the time it takes for them to meet will be $\frac {\frac {2781}{90}U}{\frac 1{180}\frac U{sec}} = 5562 sec=92 min 42 sec$.

....

Note we *never* know how fast any one person or train was going nor any of the distance or positions (except for where person 1 and 2 start at [person 1 started at $0$.  Person 2 started and $638\cdot \frac 1{180}U$].  The only thing we did know was the times when any two object pass each other and the combined speeds of Person 2 and Person 1, of Person 2 and the train, and the difference of speeds of Person 1 and the train.

Comment: This is great! Assuming person 2 stationary to apply relativity and getting the answer is done beautifully in a picturesque manner. One doubt, that had you simply written: "let/assume person 2 to be stationary and now by relativity....", this would have been easily understood but when you write the same thing in expanded manner as "Imagine the entire situation, both ..... and it will not change our answer and results." I wonder that when we look it as simply adding a constant "c" in everything's velocities, why the distance's value don't get short/stretched to finally give us a wrong result?

Comment: Thank you, upvoted!

Comment: Okay... You caught my error.  I had originally made a hiccup of $x\cdot 20 = \frac 19 \implies x =\frac 1{360}$ rather than $\frac 1{180}$ (don't ask why) I caught that and corrected it, but when it came to $-1 + 618 \cdot \frac 1{360} = \frac {129}{180}$ just editted it to $-1 + 618\frac 1{180}=\frac {129}{90}$ without actually fixing $-1+618\frac 1{360} =\frac{258}{360}$ but *not* fixing that  $-1 + 618\frac 1{180} \ne \frac {258}{180}$.  .... you must have wondered how I got that obviously wrong value.

Comment: "why the distance's value don't get short/stretched to finally give us a wrong result?"  They do get stretched!  But they get stretched consistantly.  Note what we can $1U$ and claimed it was the length of the train would be in the real world actually the length of the train minus the distance person 2 walks in 18 seconds. We don't actually know *any* distances or *any* speeds but we can solve them all in terms of one of the speeds (say $y_0$)  In solving this problem all references to $y_0$ will cancel out.  We'd have something like $t_0= whatever +some\ factor\ of y_0$ and so on.

Comment: tl;dr; I think if we say $x$ is going at such and such a speed we'll get different values for how far apart every one is, what everyones speed is and how long the train is.  But in terms of *time* any two objects cross each other the set up of the problem assures they are fixed in a locked relation with one objects speed and the length of the train as "free variables".

Comment: Hmm, alright, thanks :-)

Comment: This is indeed strange, you had edited your answer to address one of my concerns from the comments but I never got the notification for it so not checked yet. But today, revisited this question as another answer is posted. Though, thanks a lot for the explanation on changing speeds and distances but not the time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there is insufficient information.

$10$ minutes + $20$ seconds = $620$ seconds from the time the front of the train is level with Person-1, the front of the train is level with Person-2.

Assume the speeds of Person-1, Person-2, and the Train are $a,b,$ and $t$, respectively.

Assume that from the moment the **front** of the train is level with Person-1, the distance between the front of the train and Person-2 is $D$.  Note that this is also the distance, at that moment, between Person-1 and Person-2.

Let $E$ denote the length of the train.

So, you have $5$ variables:

- The speeds, $a,b,t.$
- The distances $D,E$.

So, the challenge is to express both $a$ and $b$ in terms of $D$, so that you can compute $~\displaystyle \frac{D}{a+b}.$

Once you do that, you will have the time it took for Person-1 and Person-2 to meet, starting from the distance $D$.  From this, you will have to deduct the $20 + 600 + 18$ seconds that Person-1 and Person-2 were walking towards each other, until the train passed Person-2.

So, the desired computation will be

$$\frac{D}{a+b} - 638. \tag1 $$

From the premises:

- $\displaystyle E = 20(t-a).$
- $\displaystyle E = 18(t+b).$
- $\displaystyle D = 620(t+b).$

Variable $E$ and be eliminated in favor of variable $D$.

Also, both $a$ and $b$ can be eliminated in terms of the **combination of variables**, $D$ and $t$.  Unfortunately, with only $3$ equations in $5$ variables, you can't eliminate variable $t$, in terms of variable $D$.

Therefore, there is insufficient information.

**Edit**
The above conclusion is wrong.  See my Addendum.

---

**Addendum**
See the comment following my answer,
from InanimateBeing.  When I first posted my answer, I did consider that I needed $(a+b)$, rather than explicit values for $a$ and $b$.  However, I couldn't find a way to get there.

Their comment nails the problem, and indicates how the problem should be completed.  Hijacking their concepts:

- Since $20(t-a) = 18(t+b),$ you have that 
  $2t = 20a + 18b \implies t = 10a + 9b.$
- Therefore, $(t + b) = 10a + 10b.$ 
  **This** is the part that originally escaped me!
- Therefore, 
  $D = 620(t + b) = 620(10a + 10b) = 6200(a + b).$
- Therefore, 
  $\displaystyle \frac{D}{a+b} = 6200.$
- Therefore, 
  The final computation is $6200 - 638 = 5562~$ seconds.

Comment: By equating $E=20(t−a)$ and $E=18(t+b)$ we get $t=10a+9b$ thus, $D=620(10a+10b)$. Putting it in the desired computation we'll get $\frac{620(10a+10b)}{a+b}-638=6200-638=5562=$ $92$ mins and $42$ secs. Your computation is returning this result. Please confirm

Comment: @InanimateBeing +1: Great catch!  See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer as it seems quite a plausible explanation to me but I'll wait for some more people to check this post as there's quite some different perspectives out there, as mentioned in my post too.

Answer (score 1):

Let the speed of the train be $v$, and the speed of the first person be $v_1$ and the speed of the second person be $v_2$.  At $t = 0$, the front of the train crosses the first person, so the expressions for the positions of the three objects are

$ p(t) = v t $ ( front of train )

$ p_1(t) = v_1 t  $ ( 1st person)

$ p_2(t) = d - v_2 t $ ( 2nd person )

At t = 20, the rear of the train crosses the first person, so

$ v (20) - L = v_1 (20) $

from which

$ L = 20 (v - v_1) \hspace{20pt}(1) $

At t = 620, the front of the train crosses the second person, so

$ v (620) = d - v_2 (620) \hspace{20pt}(2)$

At t = 638 , the rear of the train crosses the second person, so

$ v(638) - L = d - v_2 (638) \hspace{20pt}(3)$

Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, we deduce that

$ L = 18 (v + v_2 ) \hspace{20pt}(4) $

Now the time at which the two persons cross is $t_1$, that satisfies

$ v_1 t_1 = d - v_2 t_1 $

Thus $t_1 = \dfrac{d}{v_1 + v_2} $

Let's see how many unknowns we have.  We have

$ v , v_1, v_2, L , d $ unknown, and we have only $3$ equations relating them.

So, unless some variable gets cancelled out in the process we'll get a value for the answer otherwise it cannot be determined.

From $(1)$ and $(4)$, we have

$ L = 20( v- v_1) = 18(v + v_2) $

Therefore,

$ \dfrac{v + v_2}{v - v_1} = \dfrac{10}{9} $

From which

$ v = 10v_1 + 9v_2 $

Equation (2) gives us

$d = 620 (v + v_2) = 620 (10v_1 + 10v_2) = 6200 (v_1 + v_2) $

The two persons meet at $t_1 = \dfrac{d}{v_1 + v_2} = \dfrac{6200 (v_1 + v_2)}{v_1 + v_2} $

Hence

$ t_1 = 6200 \text{ sec} $

The time difference is $ 6200 - 638 =   5562 \text{ sec} $

Dividing by $60$ gives the required time in minutes, and this come to $92.7 \text{ minutes}$, which is equal to $92 \text{ minutes} $ and $ 42 \text{ seconds} $.

Comment: Your explanation is great! Upvoted. But you can do without the assumption and still arrive at the same answer.

Comment: Really ?  How is that ?

Comment: I edited your post, please check.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1$ be the speed of the first people, meeting the tail of the train at point $P_1$ in the space-time diagram below, and $v_2$ be the speed of the second people ($v_2>0$), meeting the tail of the train at point $P_2$, $618$ seconds after $P_1$ ($10$ minutes and $18$ seconds). If $V$ is the speed of the train and $L$ its length, the given info on "passing by" times gives
$$
L=(V-v_1)\cdot 20\ \text{s} =(V+v_2)\cdot 18\ \text{s},
$$
that is:
$$
V-v_1=9(v_1+v_2).
\tag{1}
$$
Points $P_1$ and $P_2$ are separated by an unknown distance $\Delta x$, which is covered by the train in a time interval of $618\ $s. This means that:
$$
\Delta x=V\cdot 618\ \text{s}.
\tag2
$$
On the other hand, the same distance $\Delta x$ is covered together by the two people, the second one walking for the unknown time $\Delta t$ we must find, and the first one for the time $\Delta t+618\ \text{s}$, hence:
$$
\Delta x=\Delta x_1+\Delta x_2=
v_1\cdot(\Delta t+618\ \text{s})+v_2\cdot \Delta t.
\tag3
$$
Comparing $2$ and $3$ we thus find:
$$
(V-v_1)\cdot 618\ \text{s}=(v_1+v_2)\cdot \Delta t.
\tag4
$$
We can now happily substitute $(1)$ here and, as by magic, all speeds disappear and we are left with
$$
\Delta t= 618\ \text{s}\cdot 9 = 5562\ \text{s}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Wow! So succinctly solved and never thought even a graph could be presented in such a seemingly complex situation.

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ ("units"/sec) be the speed of the train, and $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively be  the speed of the first and second person overtaken.

Since time taken is inversely proportional to speed, we can write
$\dfrac{V+v_1}{V-v_2} = \dfrac{20}{18} = \dfrac{10}{9}$

**Now using the principle that when data is missing, we can put any values that satisfy the given relation(s),**

It is easily seen that $\dfrac{10+1}{10-0.1} = \dfrac{11}{9.9} = \dfrac{10}9$,
and the rest is a walk in the park

In $10$ min + $18$ sec, the train has moved $10*618= 6180$ units, but person $1$ has reduced the distance by $0.1*618=61.8$, leaving $6118.2$ units to be covered @ $1.1$ unit/sec, giving the answer of $ 5562\;sec = 92$ min $42$ sec

---

**NOTE:**
In fact, I could have given an even simpler answer, with the relation

$\dfrac{1+k}{1-k} = \dfrac{10}{9}$, (both men walk at the same speed),
but I had the feeling that people  would jump on me and  say this is an *unwarranted assumption.* **Not so.** The question doesn't say that the two men are walking at different speeds, it is simply silent on it.

Of course, if you have to prove or show steps, it is a different matter, but otherwise we are not making *assumptions*, we are saying that in the absence of data, we can use any values that satisfy the relation(s)

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Upvoted. The principle and the note are both indeed helpful. Some questions: 1. Before $10$min and $18$secs, train had overtaken the 1st person so why the train length isn't added in the distance between the 2 persons? 2. Why "@$1$ unit/sec" and not $1.1$ unit/sec? 3. In the last $18$ secs, the 2nd person also shortens the distance by $0.1*18$ units but that's not included, why? 4. I guess it should be $1*618$ instead of $0.1*6180$.

Comment: $1:$ Time $618s$ is between the first person passed and second person passed. $2$ onwards: Corrected. *Easiest and best is using same speed for both persons.*

Comment: One last thing, you've written "but person 1 has reduced the distance by 0.1∗618=61.8" here one of "person 1" or "0.1∗618" is incorrect as person 1's speed is 1 while that of P2 is 0.1. In present state I'm unable to get why when P1 is moving the distance is getting reduced by P2's speed.

Comment: Person $1$ is the first person, overtaken in $20s$, moving behind the train towards person $2$, who will be overtaken in $18s$ Obviously, person $1$ is the slower person.

Comment: "How long after the train has passed the second person will the two people meet?" Person $2$ enters the frame only after being passed.

Comment: Ohh! Alright thanks a lot! I was simply assuming the v1 to represent speed of person 1 and similarly for P2. Using same speed for both the persons is great suggestion as rightly said that it isn't mentioned in the question though that was also the reason why I hesitated too but it's true both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Im not MSM but here's my work and two possible answers

Cite:
Two people are walking towards each other alongside a railway track.
A freight train overtakes one of them in 20 seconds
Exactly 10 minutes later meets the other person coming from the opposite direction.
The train passes this person in 18 seconds. Assume that speeds are constant throughout. How long after the train has passed the second person will the two people meet?

---

My Answer: 9 minutes and 51 seconds.

Why? Please keep reading

Values:

Train of unknown length is going one direction ---->
It takes this train 20 seconds to completely *pass* person one

Person one is walking in the same direction as the train, (at a slightly significant speed)  ----->
It takes the train 10 minutes or 600 seconds to *reach* person 2...
(They are still walking towards each other in this time frame) ----->
It takes the train 18 seconds to completely pass person two ( two seconds faster than before since he is walking in the opposite direction).

Now... answer two: 4 minutes and 42 seconds

If 1 and 2 are walking together at the combined speed of 2 seconds then the train would have presumably passed person 2 in 0 time, there is no gain or deduction in values.
Meaning if the train is 18 seconds long and it took (600 seconds), we would simply divide 600 seconds by two and reach 5 minutes, but then it also took the train 18 seconds to completely pass person 2, so lets just deduct that from our 5 minutes...

To understand my very first answer:
The train's "length" equals 19 seconds.
The two people have a combined speed of 1 second.
No matter how long it takes the train to reach person 2, person 1 and 2 is still coming together it takes less than the full (10 minutes) 600 seconds because the train took 18 seconds to pass person two.
Divide it, subtract it, voila.

- User

(I worked on this for like 30 minutes and was getting tired and confused soooo... what do you guys think?)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).